# How to destroy sessions after a user logout

Tags: wp-login-form

Hi i have a ridiculous issue with my website, if a user tries to login by using his social account like google or Facebook or twitter account and then logs out after is work but my site wont destroy the session Or cookies, because of this when he opens a browser and if if just types gmail.com the he gets directed to his inbox of same gmail account which he had used to login on my site.

So could any one help me to stop this bhevahiour, awaiting for earliest reply....

Comment: You haven't given any detail as to what plugins you've used on your site.

Comment: Also, google sessions on gmail are completely out of your control, you can't set it up so that they sign out of google when they sign out of your site, they're totally separate user sessions. If you could do that then you could go to Google and get money from their bug bounty prize fund for finding a security issue

Answer (score 1):

So:

- a user logs into Google, they are now logged into Google
- They then go to your site, and login via a social login, they are now logged into your site, and they are logged into google
- The user logs out of your site, they're now logged out of your site, but still logged into google

The problem being that you want logging out of your site to also log them out of google? **This is not possible.**

Google sessions, Google cookies, are all Google things, that you have zero control over, by design. You're not supposed to be able to do what you're trying to do, and if you could, it would be considered a major bug that must be fixed immediately.

All you can do, is tell the user to log out of Google.

Keep in mind too, that the user will not be expecting to be logged out of Google, that's not how SSO works with Social Logins. There's no reason for them to log out of Google, and having it happen unexpectedly would be annoying.

If you really wanted to do this though, you'd need to run your code on Google owned domains, the only way to do that is to work at Google

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy all user sessions from your website on user logout by using the following code.

```
function destroy_sessions() {
   $sessions->destroy_all();//destroys all sessions
   wp_clear_auth_cookie();//clears cookies regarding WP Auth
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'destroy_sessions');
```

It is called on the `wp_logout` action which you can read more about here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_logout

This will not destroy user sessions for third party websites.